# NextMethod() explicit argument performance

Tags: r, method-dispatch

With the S3 object system, in a generic method you can delegate to the next method in a class hierarchy using the `NextMethod()` function. When Wickham describes this system at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html, he uses `NextMethod()` without any arguments in his example:

```
baz <- function(x) UseMethod("baz", x)
baz.C <- function(x) c("C", NextMethod())
```

I've always used `NextMethod()` without argument in my own code as well.

---

I just noticed that `[.Date` uses an explicit argument:

```
> `[.Date`
function (x, ..., drop = TRUE) 
{
    cl <- oldClass(x)
    class(x) <- NULL
    val <- NextMethod("[")
    class(val) <- cl
    val
}
```

The documentation for `?NextMethod` says the following:

> Normally 'NextMethod' is used with only one argument, 'generic'

In terms of performance, is calling `NextMethod("generic")` faster than `NextMethod()`? Is there any other reason to prefer one usage over the other?